# MySQL error code when trying to create a function that checks data?

Tags: mysql, stored-functions

So I have two tables in my database that contain a member id. I'm trying to create a stored function that returns 0 when a member is NOT in table A but IS in table B.

Here's my code:

```
Delimiter //
CREATE FUNCTION DoesMemberExist ( mid char(10))
RETURNS INTEGER
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
IF(((SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM members 
     WHERE member_id = mid) = 0) AND ((SELECT COUNT(*) 
                                       FROM rent_equipment_log
                                       WHERE member_id = mid) > 0)) THEN
RETURN 0;
ELSE RETURN 1;
END IF;
END;
```

The error I'm getting is 1064 and it's saying there's a problem with my syntax but I can't figure out whats wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize [`EXISTS()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) instead. Also, `END IF` was missing to end the `IF` clause.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION DoesMemberExist ( mid char(10))
RETURNS INTEGER
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
  IF( NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM members 
                 WHERE member_id = mid) 
      AND 
      EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM rent_equipment_log 
             WHERE member_id = mid) ) THEN 
    RETURN 0;
  ELSE RETURN 1;
  END IF;   -- We need to END the IF clause
END //
DELIMITER ;   -- Redefine the delimiter back to ;
```

Comment: Thanks for that! It works great. I'm trying to call this function in a trigger and once again I am getting a syntax error. The purpose of the trigger is to delete the row in "rented_equipment_log" containing a member_id that has been removed from "members".                                                

This is the trigger:
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER DeleteMember 
AFTER DELETE ON members
DECLARE MC INTEGER;
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
SELECT DoesMemberExist(OLD.member_id) INTO mc;
IF (mc = 0) THEN
DELETE FROM rented_equipment_log  WHERE member_id = OLD.member_id;
END IF;
END;//

Comment: @rookiecookie It calls for a different context, hence different question :) I will be happy to assist you in a different question.

Comment: I accepted it as the answer :) Unfortunately I cannot ask a question for another 2 days. Is there any other way of contacting you?

Comment: @rookiecookie let me check the trigger code you sent. also specify the exact error message you are getting

Comment: @rookiecookie `DECLARE MC INTEGER;` will come after `for each row begin`.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE MC INTEGER;
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
SELECT DoesMemberExist(OLD.member_id) I' at line 3

Comment: Okay I moved DECLARE MC INTEGER to after for each row begin and am still getting an error message.
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF (MC = 0) THEN
DELETE FROM rented_equipment_log  WHERE member_id = OLD.member' at line 7

Comment: @rookiecookie MC at the time of declaration is in capital letters, while you are using it in lowecase in `select`. Ensure that proper case is followed. By the way, we can chat here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11391/sql

Comment: I don't have a 20 reputation so I can't type in the chat, but the code is working now. Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you have an email that I can contact you on?

Comment: I sent you an email. Thanks!